# How do i make two buttons open a different dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dialog

I want it to work like this:

```
+-----------+                   +--------------------+
|  button1  |------------------->| I am a dialog box. |
+-----------+                   +--------------------+

+-----------+                                       +-------------+
|  button2  |--------------------------------------->| Hello World |
+-----------+                                       +-------------+
```

But it ends up like this:

```
+-----------+                   +--------------------+
|  button1  |------------------->| I am a dialog box. |
+-----------+                   +--------------------+

+-----------+
|  button2  |
+-----------+
```

```
<button class="o">How To Make MadLibs in JS</button>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
  if (document.querySelector('.o')) {
    document.querySelector('.o').onclick = function() {
      dialog.show();
    };
  }
  if (document.querySelector('.c')) {
    document.querySelector('.c').onclick = function() {
      dialog.close();
    };
  }
  if (document.querySelector('.p')) {
    document.querySelector('.p').onclick = function() {
      print();
      dialog.close();
    };
  }
});
```

If you need more code to fix it, it's here: https://lesscodegreater--seamore.repl.co/

I tried using the ai generate one, tried using stack overflow answers, none of it worked, none of it made sense, i'm resorting to asking now.

also, i'm using the dialog TAG, not some other thing, I'm using `<dialog>`.

Comment: You would need either 1 instance of a modal for each box (ie. 2 in this case) OR you would need to dynamically update the content of a single modal depending on whichever button was clicked to trigger the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to distinct the two buttons and two dialogs somehow. Giving them an `id` field would do the job.

```html
<button class="o" id="dna-btn">How to make DNA ... </button>
<button class="o" id="madlibs-btn">How to make MadLibs ... </button>
```

2. After that, you have to distinct your two dialogs. Using the `id` attribute here as well

```html
<dialog id="dna-dialog"> ... </dialog>
<dialog id="madlibs-dialog"> ... </dialog>
```

3. Modify the js to use the newly created ids

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const dnaDialog = document.querySelector('#dna-dialog');

  if (document.querySelector('#dna-btn')) {
    document.querySelector('#dna-btn').onclick = function() {
      dnaDialog.show();
    };
  }

  if (document.querySelector('.c')) {
    document.querySelector('.c').onclick = function() {
      dnaDialog.close();
    };
  }

  if (document.querySelector('.p')) {
    document.querySelector('.p').onclick = function() {
      print();
      dnaDialog.close();
    };
  }

  const madlibsDialog = document.querySelector('#madlibs-dialog');

  if (document.querySelector('#madlibs-btn')) {
    document.querySelector('#madlibs-btn').onclick = function() {
      madlibsDialog.show();
    };
  }
});
```

#### Optional

Also it would reduce the javascript code if you used `onclick` attributes on the buttons.

```html
<button class="o" onclick="dna.show()" >How to make DNA ... </button>
<button class="o" onclick="madlibs.show()">How to make MadLibs ... </button>
...
<dialog id="dna-dialog"> ... </dialog>
<dialog id="madlibs-dialog"> ... </dialog>
```

```js
const dna = document.getElementById('dna-dialog');
const madlibs = document.getElementById('madlibs-dialog');
```